# Inserting binary data via QSQL

Tags: c++, sql, qt

How to insert binary data to table "test" from "database" with 2 columns text "name" and bin "pic"

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
 db.setUserName("user");
 db.setPassword("pwd");
 db.setPort(1234);
 db.setDatabaseName("database");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/UsingsqldatabasefromQt.htm snippets

First you need to open the DB `db.open();`

One way would be

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO test (name, pic) "
              "VALUES (:name, :pic)");
query.bindValue(":name", "Bart");
query.bindValue(":pic", "Bart.jpg");
query.exec();
```